# How can I make it so that I can add special attacks in the editor instead of repeatedly adding for loops?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development, coding-efficiency

I have this code that lets me handle button combinations in Unity:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class InputBufferScriptTest: MonoBehaviour {
  public enum FightInput {
    Up,
    UpRight,
    Right,
    DownRight,
    Down,
    DownLeft,
    Left,
    UpLeft,
    LightPunch,
    MediumPunch,
    HeavyPunch, 
    LightKick,
    MediumKick,  
    HeavyKick   
  }
    List<FightInput> recentInputs = new List<FightInput>();

    public List<FightInput> Special1Inputs = new List<FightInput>();

    public List<FightInput> Special2Inputs = new List<FightInput>();

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {
    

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W)) 
    {
            recentInputs.Add(FightInput.Up);
            Debug.Log("UP");
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
    {
            recentInputs.Add(FightInput.Down);
            Debug.Log("DOWN");
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A)) 
    {
            recentInputs.Add(FightInput.Left);
            Debug.Log("LEFT");
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D)) 
    {
            recentInputs.Add(FightInput.Right);
            Debug.Log("RIGHT");
            
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.U))
    {
            recentInputs.Add(FightInput.LightPunch);
            Debug.Log("LIGHT PUNCH");
    }    
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.I))
    {
            recentInputs.Add(FightInput.MediumPunch);
            Debug.Log("MEDIUM PUNCH");
    }    
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.O))
    {
            recentInputs.Add(FightInput.HeavyPunch);
            Debug.Log("HEAVY PUNCH");
    }    
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.J))
    {
            recentInputs.Add(FightInput.LightKick);
            Debug.Log("LIGHT KICK");
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.K))
    {
            recentInputs.Add(FightInput.MediumKick);
            Debug.Log("MEDIUM KICK");
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.L))
    {
            recentInputs.Add(FightInput.HeavyKick);
            Debug.Log("HEAVY KICK");
    }

    for (int i = recentInputs.Count - 1, j = Special1Inputs.Count - 1; i >= 0 && j >= 0; --i, --j) {

      FightInput input = recentInputs[i];

      FightInput nextSpecial1Input = Special1Inputs[j];

      if (input != nextSpecial1Input) {

        break;

      } else if (j == 0) {

        //Combo was entered, do Special1 then empty the list
          
        Debug.Log("Special1!");

        recentInputs.Clear();

      }

    }

    for (int i = recentInputs.Count - 1, j = Special2Inputs.Count - 1; i >= 0 && j >= 0; --i, --j) {

      FightInput input = recentInputs[i];

      FightInput nextSpecial2Input = Special2Inputs[j];

      if (input != nextSpecial2Input) {

        break;

      } else if (j == 0) {

        //Combo was entered, do Special2 then empty the list
          
        Debug.Log("Special2!");

        recentInputs.Clear();

      }

    }

    float secondsSinceLastInput = 0;

    secondsSinceLastInput += Time.deltaTime;

    if (secondsSinceLastInput > 1) {
      recentInputs.Clear();
    }
  }
}
```

It works by me making a special attack list (`public List<FightInput> Special1Inputs = new List<FightInput>();` for example). And then in the editor I can choose how many buttons are needed to trigger the special attack, then I get a drop down list to choose which button  should be pressed for each step in the chain. The issue is if I wanted to have 5 special attacks, I'd have to repeat `public List<FightInput> Special1Inputs = new List<FightInput>();` 5 times, name them individually, and copy and paste the for loop 5 times and make them correspond to the right special attack. Is there a way I can add special attacks in the editor? I was thinking of it going something like getting an "Add a special attack" field in the editor, and then Once I do I can name the special attack, and give it its number of inputs and its required buttons. Or maybe there's a better way to handle doing this that I haven't realised yet

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you need a list of `List<FightInput>` like `List<List<FightInput>>`.
Sadly for this to work in unity editor, you would need to write a wrapper to be able to use it:

```
[Serializable]
public class InputList
{
    public List<FightInput> fightInputs;
}
public List<InputList> specialAttacks;
```

This way, you will be able to assign multiple special attacks without creating multiple variables. Just be sure to change loops - you would need to put your current loops inside a bigger loop that iterates over specialAttakcs list.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfBlc.jpg - result in the editor

Of course you can create custom editor to add special attacks, if you wish so. If you want to go this path, maybe you should consider using ScriptableObject.